# MySQL query to return json name value

Tags: php, mysql, json

I'm working with a table in which information is stored in a table in JSON format. The JSON value field looks like:

select * from k2_extra_fields where id = 2 and published = 1;

```
id | value        
2,[{"name":"Apples","value":1,"target":null,"alias":"","required":0,"showNull":1},{"name":"Pears","value":2,"target":null,"alias":"","required":0,"showNull":1},{"name":"Mangos","value":3,"target":null,"alias":"","required":0,"showNull":1},{"name":"Guava","value":4,"target":null,"alias":"Fruit","required":0,"showNull":1},{"name":"Pineapple","value":5,"target":null,"alias":"Fruit","required":0,"showNull":1}]
```

Or values in a simple line by line view (minus the ID):

```
[
  {"name":"Apples","value":1,"target":null,"alias":"","required":0,"showNull":1},
  {"name":"Pears","value":2,"target":null,"alias":"","required":0,"showNull":1},
  {"name":"Mangos","value":3,"target":null,"alias":"","required":0,"showNull":1},
  {"name":"Guava","value":4,"target":null,"alias":"Fruit","required":0,"showNull":1},
  {"name":"Pineapple","value":5,"target":null,"alias":"Fruit","required":0,"showNull":1}
]
```

The query that leads me here returns the value of 3. 3 = Mangos. How do I take the '3' value and match it up with the stored names/values so that I end up with the output, Mangos?

Comment: I'm slightly confused. What is your expected output? Just the word 'Mangos'?

Comment: Yes, Mangos. From a previous query I am able to get the value of "3" which corresponds to mangos. However, how do you do the query that takes 3, matches the correct json-formatted field for 3 and pulls out Mangos? This could be PHP or MySQL.

Answer (score 0):

It should be possible with build in mysql functionality, but very hard and 'not clever' idea to do. If you really need to compute this problem within mysql, you would need to actually add new funtionality to your mysql. Look up on UDF plugins: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/udf-compiling.html

Comment: Thanks but that would be beyond my skillset; what about a PHP option? How would you go about wrting a function or some if statements that would match the '3' and extract 'Mangos' as the output? There must be a function designed to handle this. Writing a complicated oneoff based upon some pattern matching on "value":3 and everything between the surrounding {} seems rather inefficient.

Comment: PHP variant: http://pastebin.com/cF52srdm ; Tip - once you parsed it with php, you can write it all into a new mysql table. But you would need to re-run script to update such table everytime you got new json string.

Comment: I tested your code; that is the general idea. I ought to be able to figure out how to pass '3' or whatever to the code; that's on me. Some background here - I work with Joomla CMS and use one of their extensions called K2; the presentation of K2 is not always to our needs so I occasionally write PHP scripts to suit the need. K2's extra fields data which can be extremely useful in administering content is stored in JSON format. Being able to roll my own presentation will help substantially.